# Javascript blob to image converting with JSZip

Tags: javascript, blob, jszip

```
var bl = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response)

var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file(bl);

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");

}, function(err){
    console.log(err)
})
```

My XmlHttpRequest got a response of the type 'blob' from an image file. How can I convert the blob image file to an image file (could be .gif, .jpg, .bmp, .jpg-large, etc.) so that I can make a zip file without errors?

Comment: [.file](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_name.html) when passed a single argument trys to get a file not set a file. To set a [file](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html) you need to pass it two arguments, the name, and the content (it can be the blob you got)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `URL.createObjectURL` you get the url of the blob (`blob:https://stackoverflow.com/e62c177a-b4b1-4945-8e13-53bb5a3c8f34` for example). JSZip doesn't resolve it but you can use the blob (so `xhr.response` in your case) directly. As Patrick Evans said in a comment, you also need to give the file name.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("my_file.ext", xhr.response);

zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
.then(function(content) {
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
}, function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Related issue on GitHub https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/246